# Using Forms in SharePoint

Tags: 2013, workflow, forms-authentication

I'm currently working on a project that wants me to develop something in SharePoint that would allow me to upload multiple documents related to one another. The client wants to see each document in a form view for easy access and the ability to enter new data for new documents. For example, an event request is entered into SharePoint and there are 5 or 6 pages of corresponding data that need to be linked to the one event. I want each page to have its own form so data can be entered in by a user. Then, we want to be able to set up a workflow using all of the corresponding sections of one event request for approvals. Does any of this make sesnse and can anyone help me figure out how to set this up?

- software & access needed?
- How to restrict access to certain documents?
- How to show corresponding pages in form view?
- How to route everything in a workflow?

Comment: What SharePoint version are you using? What would cause a document to need to be restricted?

Comment: SharePoint 2013. Restrictions as in not allowing for overwriting or edits to be made. Some users don't need to see certain documents so they wouldn't have access to view them.

Comment: Define 'certain documents', though. Are you talking about a name, a status, content, document type, form value?

Comment: By certain documents, I mean one of the forms with the populated data. Only certain people in my organization need to have access to the data, but the whole organization uses SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

(NOTE: There are a couple of semi-advanced front end things you'll need to know if you aren't an experienced user, I've noted those in 5 and 7)

1. You'll most likely need to be a site owner for the site you want to do this on if you're going to do everything yourself. You'll also need SharePoint Designer 2013 and InfoPath 2013 for your local machine (local admin rights to install). This can also be done in Visual Studio for the best results, but if you're asking these questions, you may not be comfortable there/possessing of enough rights.
2. In your custom list, under advanced settings set the read and create/edit access to "read/created/edit items that were created by user". A specific permission (cancel checkout for instance) would be required to read/edit all items. You would grant this to those who need to know.  You can also set the 'Launch forms in a dialog?' value to launch forms in a modal dialog vs a full page.
3. Create the columns you need in SharePoint through the front-end/browser side of the site or SP Designer.
4. In SharePoint designer, go to the custom list you've created and use the 'Design Forms in InfoPath' link to your form item.
5. Create the form you want here. This is the first of a couple of bits of self-training you'll need if you don't know what you're doing. If you have a multi-page form, you'll want to use a button to switch views (each 'page' of your form is a view) to go over to the next page and then on your last page, submit the form.
6. You'll probably want to create a separate form for displaying submitted items since the fields requested for submittal may not be the ones you want to display to your managers/reviewers.
7. Use SharePoint Designer to create a workflow based on the submitted information. This is the other bit of self-training you'd want to do if you don't know what you're doing.